# Infopath Send Current Form to Different Form upon Submission

Tags: infopath, infopath-forms-services

I have an infopath form, is there anyway to get this current infopath form and once submit is clicked, have it go to another form or show a different set of fields upon press [submit] ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is some kind of multi-step form, you could use *views*. InfoPath Views allow to display different fields depending on the view, and you can add buttons to navigate from one view to an other. You may also evaluate some rules before switching to an other view (for example to check for mandatory fields).